# What is the difference between uninstalling an application via the windows 10 "Settings" app and the legacy Control Panel?

Tags: uninstall, uac, windows-installer, installshield

We have an MSI based InstallShield product installation, it was recently pointed out to us that when our product is uninstalled via the legacy "Control Panel" "Programs and Features" app the blue UAC prompt is used indicating that the uninstaller that Windows is using is properly signed, however when our app is uninstalled using the "Settings" "Apps & features" app the yellow UAC prompt is used indicating that the uninstaller that Windows is using is NOT signed. How and why do these two methods of launching an application's uninstaller differ and how do we go about making sure that our customers are running a signed copy of our uninstaller in all circumstances?

--- Edit ---

A screenshot of the UAC prompt that is received

[image: The UAC Prompt]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound I could, but a screenshot of a UAC prompt wouldn't be all that useful because it'll block out all other open windows.  What information are you trying to learn?

Comment: The exact message you have received, as to the reason, would take to long to explain